# CLI powershell Cmdlet documentation

Tags: powershell

Is there any other way to access Powershell Cmdlet documentation within Powershell besides `Get-Help`? The pages returned by `Get-Help` are deficient at *best*.

Comment: Did you run `Update-Help` ?

Comment: For the core PowerShell cmdlets the help will be the same as MS Docs so long as you successfully run `Update-Help` as others have suggested. `-Detailed` and `-Full` give more information. `-Online` will take you to the MS Docs documentation page in your default browser.  For example: `Get-Help Get-Process -Online` will open the `Get-Process` help page.

Also useful `-ShowWindow` which will open in a separate window with a Find prompt.  I find this useful when I'm crafting a command and want the help open on a separate screen without 1 more rouge Chrome tab...

Comment: I usually just google the command and read the help online.

Comment: @js2010 I was trying to avoid the need to switch focus to a browser for lookups.

Comment: @Olaf No, I did not! Thanks, I will try this. I have lots of scripting experience in *nix-verse. Now that I am interacting with locked down win10, I'm embracing PS solutions.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This showed a slight improvement in the case of *some* Cmdlets.

Comment: @Olaf, This is the behavior I'm used to when requesting man pages from CLIs! Post an answer and I will select.

Comment: Also `Get-Help command -Full` emits all the information. Using `help command -Full` will emit one page at a time (like `more`).